# Qty in cart to dropdown and automatic update

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, quantity

I've managed to convert the basket qty to a dropdown.

Any ideas how I can update the basket upon selection of dropdown value, as oppose to selecting "Update Cart".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not an magento issue, and relates to how to use javascript to deal with element change events

Comment: Customising magento is not a magento issue? If this portal is for "magento issues", then lets all use the default theme and report bugs on here only. You <div></div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've kept the templates default structure so that the cart products are in a form and the original qty field id/name is being used you should be able to just add `onchange="this.form.submit()"` to the select.